# line 60, in make_tuple return tuple(l) TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Vector'

Tags: python, class, vector, iteration, pygame

I am new to Vectors and making classes. I am trying to construct my own vector class but when i pass it through my code which is:

position += heading*distance_moved

where position and heading are both vectors. heading is normalized. my goal is to repeat my code until position = destination.
What is wrong with this class?

import math

```
class Vector(object):
    #defaults are set at 0.0 for x and y
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    #allows us to return a string for print
    def __str__(self):
        return "(%s, %s)"%(self.x, self.y)

    # from_points generates a vector between 2 pairs of (x,y) coordinates
    @classmethod
    def from_points(cls, P1, P2):
        return cls(P2[0] - P1[0], P2[1] - P1[1])

    #calculate magnitude(distance of the line from points a to points b
    def get_magnitude(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x**2+self.y**2)

    #normalizes the vector (divides it by a magnitude and finds the direction)
    def normalize(self):
        magnitude = self.get_magnitude()
        self.x/= magnitude
        self.y/= magnitude

    #adds two vectors and returns the results(a new line from start of line ab to end of line bc)
    def __add__(self, rhs):
        return Vector(self.x +rhs.x, self.y+rhs.y)

    #subtracts two vectors
    def __sub__(self, rhs):
        return Vector(self.x - rhs.x, self.y-rhs.y)

    #negates or returns a vector back in the opposite direction
    def __neg__(self):
        return Vector(-self.x, -self.y)

    #multiply the vector (scales its size) multiplying by negative reverses the direction
    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        return Vector(self.x*scalar, self.y*scalar)

    #divides the vector (scales its size down)
    def __div__(self, scalar):
        return Vector(self.x/scalar, self.y/scalar)

    #iterator
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    #next
    def next(self):
        self.current += 1
        return self.current - 1

    #turns a list into a tuple
    def make_tuple(l):
        return tuple(l)
```

Answer (score 32):

I guess you are using python 3.x, because I've got a similar error.
I'm also new on making class, but it would be nice to share what I learned :)

In 3.x, use `__next__()` instead of `next()` in the definition of classes.
The error haven't occurred after I renamed it in your code, but I got another problem, "'Vector' object has no attribute 'current'" :)

I think it might be better for you to understand iterators (and class?) more.
A simplest example is:

```
class Count:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.max = n

    def __iter__(self):
        self.count = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count == self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        self.count += 1
        return self.count - 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Count(4)
    for i in c:
        print(i, end = ',')
```

and the outputs are 0,1,2,3,.

With a vector class, I want to iterate the components of the vector. So:

```
def __iter__(self):
    self.count = 0
    self.list = [self.x, self.y, self.z]  # for three dimension
    return self

def __next__(self):
    if self.count == len(self.list):
        raise StopIteration
    self.count += 1
    return self.list[self.count - 1]
```

and the iterator outputs the sequence x, y, z.

Note that the most important feature of iterators is to give the sequence step by step without creating whole list. So it is not very good idea to make `self.list` if the sequence will be very long.
More details here: [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators)

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me. Now if only the docs weren't so horrendously out of date and incomplete, we might all have avoided this.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument that's being passed into `make_tuple` is your `Vector` instance (it's the same `self` argument that you put everywhere).

You have to pass in *what* you want to turn into a tuple, which is probably your x and y coordinates:

```
def make_tuple(self):
    return (self.x, self.y)
```